# In a Lua file called foo.lua, what would the difference be between a variable called self.bar, foo.bar, and bar?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Parallel with my example is that I'm building a game and have a class called player.lua.

I coded this a few weeks back when I didn't really know how Lua worked, so I didn't have a table for the player constructed.

I have assigned various attributes to the player, such as self.speed or self.strength. I was hoping (and it works) that these attributes will all be the player's.

I have questions that I can't seem to find a logical, intuitive answer to.

If I had declared a table (player = {}) inside player.lua, then player.speed would refer to the "speed" key of the player table. But without such a table, what am I currently actually doing?

What if I used player.speed instead of self.speed in player.lua instead?

What if in the future I want to have multiple player's in the same game at the same time? How do I "instantiate multiple instances of the same class" as I would in Java, but in Lua? Would this basically involve having a central game lua file, say main.lua or game.lua, then constructing a table of players, of which each element is a player table itself?

Say, listofPlayers = {}
and you would go:
table.insert(listOfPlayers, player:new()) where player:new() would instantiate a new table with all the default attributes of a player, and then return that table?

Then when do I use metatables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Metatables

Metatables are used to overload common operations in the language. These operations can include such things as addition, multiplation, equality comparisons and (as the name would imply) table like operations such as accessing a value via a key `table[key]`.

Metatables are often used to implement Object Oriented programming in Lua. The primary mechanism by which this is driven is the use of `__index`. This example will illustrate this in the most basic form:

```
>>> parent = {parentID = 'Secret'}
>>> child = {}
>>> setmetatable(child,{__index=parent})
>>> =child.parentID
Secret
```

The key `parentID` doesn't actually exist within child, so **nowhere** in child is there something like the following:

```
child = {
        parentID = 'Secret'
    }
```

Instead, we've made it such that when someone looks for a key which doesn't exist within `child`, we go and look in `parent`, this was set in the *metatable* which we assigned to table in:

```
>>> setmetatable(child,{__index=parent})
```

So programmatically the flow of events when we ask for `child.parentID` is:

1. Does `child` contain a key,value pair for which key is `"parentID"`? No, therefore go to 2.
2. Does `child` have `__index` defined in it's metatable? Yes, go to 3.
3. Look in the table referenced by `__index` to check for the key `"parentID"`
4. Found in parent! return the value of `parent["parentID"]`

So this allows us to create *relationships* between tables. We can make relationships between a table which represents information for all players, and each player themselves using the `__index` metatable method like so:

```
Player = { }
    Player_metatable = {
        __index = Player --look for the missing key in the Player table
    }

    function Player.new(name)
        aPlayer = { name = name } 
        setmetatable(aPlayer,Player_metatable)
        return aPlayer
    end 

    function Player:rotate()
        print("I'M ROTATING",tostring(self))
    end 

    henry =  Player.new("Henry")
    henry:rotate()
```

When we call `Player.new("Henry")` we create a table, and set its metatable to `Player_metatable`, just like setting the metatable of `child` in the first example. However we're just doing it inside a function rather than straight of the bat, there's no difference!

When we call `henry:rotate()` what happens like outlined above is: We look for a key `"rotate"` in `henry`, but find none so we look in `Player` (because that's the table which `__index` points to in our metatable). There we have a *function* associated with that key. So you we then invoke that function, passing ourself in because of the `t:function` syntax.

To create *instances* of a class, you just need to assign a table, the metatable which *points* to the table where you've defiend class behaviour. So we could create as many Player's as we wanted with:

```
my_player_name = Player.new(...)
```

Modifying values in the `Player` table, will be reflected in all tables with the associated metatable.

Comment: Good description; you may want to mention that if in step 4 the key isn't found, then parent's metatable will be checked, so these can be chained.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand it in the context you're explaining, but I'm still lost as to how to implement it. I have a main.lua with the code you provided me [here](http://repl.it/J1m) as well as Player.lua with the following code [here](http://repl.it/J1l). I'm getting a "attempt to call field 'new' (a nil value)" error in main.lua. What I'm trying to do is to instantiate the Player instances in my main.lua code, not my Player.lua code. How do I do this?

Comment: You need to bring the `Player` table into scope. Lua won't look inside .lua files for a variable it can't find in the existing one. You can import the `Player` table like so in you main.lua: `Player = require("Player")` this will load the Player.lua. the assignment is required IF the Player table is defined as local in which case add `return Player` to Player.lua

Answer (score 2):

HennyH has a good description for how metatables can be used and what they give you, but to answer your question directly, let's say your Player table includes one method `name`:

```
local Player = {}
local name
function Player:name()
  return self.name -- #1
  return Player.name -- #2
  return name -- #3
end
```

- #1 uses `name` field of the `self` table, which is what you'd use most of the time as it allows to use metatables to implement class inheritance. `self` will reference whatever table `name` method is called for (which may not be `Player` if the method is found through `__index` references)
- #2 uses `name` field of the `Player` table, ignoring any references to the actual `self` object. This may be useful if you want to have some player-specific data that should not be affected by inherited classes.
- #3 uses a local variable. It's in many ways similar to `Player.name` with one significant difference: it allows you to implement private elements of your "class". Note that some code that uses `Player` class can access and modify `Player.name` as it pleases. this is not the case when this method is used as the only way to access `name` when it's a local variable is through closures that have this variable as an upvalue. If you don't provide a method to modify it, it's going to be read-only.

Each option has its own uses, but #1 is what you probably see most frequently.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it now. As far as I understand, if I passed in an instance of a Player into the function, say:  


`function Player:name(p)
   return self.name -- returns Player p's name
`

Then it would be like the `this` keyword in Java.


#2 is like a "static variable", or you can think of it as a Player's default variable. If we modified this here it better be a good reason, because now all the other Player.name references will be different.

#3 is what you said.

Comment: @Gary, yes, except you don't have `Player:name(p)`, just `Player:name()` and you get `self` that captures whatever table that name for called on.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Would you also know what I'm doing wrong in the comment I posted above? I've linked two snippets of code for main.lua and player.lua with just the initial constructors but I'm always stumped by getting one class to call functions properly from the other.

Comment: @Gary, remove `module(..., package.seeall)` and `return Player` at the end. You can also add `local` in front of `Player` and `Player_metatable`.

Comment: Thanks that worked great. I've been putting the `module(..., package.seeall)` line in all my non-main.lua code files up to now since I thought it would make the main.lua file "see" it; what does `return Player` actually return, and when is it called/triggered? Also, I'm assuming that `local` should be used pretty much everywhere since it optimizes runtime, or is there more to it?

Comment: @Gary lookup is *much* faster for local variables. It is also preferable not to use globals as they generally introduce coupling to the design of the program. (this is one of many reasons).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to inherits from a different class is copying all methods, possibly via a "new" method. In this was you can mix and match from many classes.
Lua just copy a reference to the method so the memory overhead is minimal

```
prototype={}
--add some methods to prototype
function prototype:new()
 local newtable={}
 for k,v in pairs(self) do
   newtabke[k]=v
 end
 return newtable
end
```